# pyodbc is returning binary data in char field

Tags: python, sql, database, pyodbc, ibm-midrange

pyodbc with driver "iSeries Access ODBC Driver" is returning binary output, Ex:

original data in the table: B06300

what it returns: b'\xc2\xf0\xf6\xf3\xf0\xf0@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'

My code:

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect(
    driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
    System='**************',
    port = '****',
    uid='**************',
    pwd='**************')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM schema_name.F4108")
```

I tried putting add_output_converter and encoder to connection but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the data is defined on the server as CCSID 65535, which means to not translate the data.

Using the TRANSLATE=1 connection string keyword will cause the ODBC driver to translate the data using the current EBCDIC CCSID for the job.  Other ODBC connection properties can be found here:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=keywords-connection-string-conversion-properties